# How to indicate data type in com port communication

Tags: c#, serial-port

I should write a program that send and receives small size images and also text messages using COM port in c#. how can i find what data is now received and do appropriate operation on it (for text display in grid and for image show on picturebox) in *DataReceived* event.
for text messages i use `comPort.ReadExisting()` and for pictures i use `_comport.Read()` method.

Comment: Very unclear... Do you need to implement both sides? Who defines communication protocol? Does information come over single port or multiple (based on the fact you show very different pices of code to read text/binary)...

Comment: I think the "Read" method can read a char array. You can convert your image to a string/chararray and send. For start and end you can use special tags.

Comment: You should define and implement a communication protocol. For example you may send your data as [Start Signature][DataTypeID][Data][CRC][End Signature]. When you'll receive this data you should extract a data packet by signatures, verify the checksum and then process the data using the DataTypeID.